# Label text not updating after scroll event

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scrollview

I'm trying to update text of a label after a scroll event.  I have a print command that prints the correct value but the label is not updating.
Here's my code

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let w = scrollView.bounds.size.width
    let p = Int(x/w)
    print("page \(p)")   // this prints correct value
    self.signalLabel.text = signalText[Int(x/w)]  // this does not update
}
```

what's the deal?

Here's the complete view controller code. This view is called from a button click on the initial view controller. This view contains a UIScrollView and UIPageControl. The UIScrollView contains two images that can be scrolled back and forth. I want to update the label text based on image that is shown.

```
import UIKit

class SignalOneViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var signalScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var signalPageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var signalLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: - Button Actions
@IBAction func signalOneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("signal one button clicked")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignalOneSegue", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func onCancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


let signalImages = ["signal1a.png", "signal1b.png"]
let signalText = ["Ready for play", "Untimed down"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.loadScrollView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadScrollView() {
    let pageCount : CGFloat = CGFloat(signalImages.count)
    signalLabel.text = signalText[0]

    signalScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    signalScrollView.delegate = self
    signalScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    signalScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: signalScrollView.frame.size.width * pageCount, height: signalScrollView.frame.size.height)
    signalScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    signalScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    signalPageControl.numberOfPages = Int(pageCount)
    signalPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    signalPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blue
    signalPageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageChanged), for: .valueChanged)

    for i in 0..<Int(pageCount) {
        print(self.signalScrollView.frame.size.width)
        let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.signalScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: self.signalScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.signalScrollView.frame.size.height))
        image.image = UIImage(named: signalImages[i])!
        image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        self.signalScrollView.addSubview(image)
    }
}

//MARK: UIScrollView Delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
    // content offset - tells by how much the scroll view has scrolled.
    let pageNumber = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - viewWidth / 50) / viewWidth) + 1
    signalPageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let w = scrollView.bounds.size.width
    let p = Int(x/w)
    print("page \(p)")
    self.signalLabel.text = signalText[p]
    print(">>> \(signalText[Int(x/w)])")
}

//MARK: page tag action
@objc func pageChanged() {
    let pageNumber = signalPageControl.currentPage
    var frame = signalScrollView.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(pageNumber)
    frame.origin.y = 0
    signalScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

}

Comment: Is `self.signalLabel` nil? Is that code called in main thread?

Comment: try to print this and tell us what it returns: `print(">>> \(signalText[Int(x/w)])")`

Comment: what is the type of `signalText`?

Comment: self.signalLabel is initialized to a value starting off.  This view contains a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl and is opened from a button click on the initial view controller. The UIScrollView contains two images that can be scrolled back and forth. I want the label updated based on the image that's shown.

Comment: `self.signalLabel` is not nil, otherwise it would crash. `signalText[Int(x/w)]` could return nil (notice that you print page, not the text from signalText), if `signalText` is a dictionary `[Int:String]` and there is no value for the key `Int(x/w)`. If it is an array, then it would crash if there was not a value for it. So finally, the last thing that comes up to mind is that `self.signalLabel` is not the label that you think it is, and presented label is another object. Can you show the rest of that view controller code?

Comment: the print command above prints the correct value. `self.signalLabel` is initialized to a starting value in the beginning. `signalText` is defined this way `let signalText = ["string1", "string2"]`

Comment: as for the thread question - this view is opened from a button click on the initial view.  The current view contains UIScrollView and UIPageControl. The UIScrollView contains two images that can be scrolled back and forth. I want to update the label based on the image that's shown.  I am using storyboard.

Comment: interesting, the code seems to be OK (although it's hard to be sure, just by looking at it and not playing around with it)... can you confirm that the `signalLabel` is connected to the correct label in storyboards?

Comment: It started working when I changed the UILabel to UITextField.  Don't know why I didn't try that earlier.

Comment: @PhilipCole that's like the weirdest thing I have seen today.. anyway, good luck with coding!

Comment: It only worked until I made another view and recompiled.  Now it doesn't work. I don't understand.  Would the simulator cause the update issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure signalLabe **IBOutlet** is attached to your label in storyboard or xib